# Updating data-frame column and losing date index

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes

df1:

```
            col2  col3 dept
date                       
2020-05-06    29    21    A
2020-05-07    56    12    B
2020-05-08    82    15    C
2020-05-09    13     9    D
2020-05-10    35    13    E
2020-05-11    53    87    F
2020-05-12    25     9    G
2020-05-13    23    63    H
```

df2:

```
            col2 dept
date                 
2020-05-06    64    A
2020-05-07    41    B
2020-05-08    95    C
2020-05-09    58    D
2020-05-10    89    E
2020-05-11    37    F
2020-05-12    24    G
2020-05-13    67    H
```

I want to update column `col2` in `df1` with the values in column `col2` in `df2` so my output looks like:

```
            col2  col3 dept
date                       
2020-05-06    64    21    A
2020-05-07    41    12    B
2020-05-08    95    15    C
2020-05-09    58     9    D
2020-05-10    89    13    E
2020-05-11    37    87    F
2020-05-12    24     9    G
2020-05-13    67    63    H
```

I have written some code that looks like:

```
df1=df1.set_index('dept')
df1.update(df2.set_index('dept'))
df1=df1.reset_index()
```

However it resets the index in `df1` to integers and not dates so the output I am getting looks like:

```
  dept  col2  col3
0    A    64    21
1    B    41    12
2    C    95    15
3    D    58     9
4    E    89    13
5    F    37    87
6    G    24     9
7    H    67    63
```

My complete code is below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import datetime
dept=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
date_today = datetime.date.today()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')
np.random.seed(seed=1111)
data1 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
data2 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': days, 'dept':dept,'col2': data1, 'col3': data2})
df1 = df1.set_index('date')

print(df1)

dept=['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
date_today = datetime.date.today()
days = pd.date_range(date_today, date_today + timedelta(7), freq='D')
np.random.seed(seed=1331)
data3 = np.random.randint(1, high=100, size=len(days))

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': days, 'dept':dept,'col2': data3})
df2 = df2.set_index('date')

print(df2)

df1=df1.set_index('dept')
df1.update(df2.set_index('dept'))
df1=df1.reset_index()

print(df1)
```

How can I update `df1` with `df2` and keep the index date format in `df1`?

Answer (score 1):

As I understand on your sample, you update `df1` from `df2` base on both `date` index and column `dept`. You need to add `dept` to index and call `update`

```
df1 = df1.set_index('dept', append=True)
df1 = df1.update(df2.set_index('dept', append=True))
df1 = df1.reset_index('dept')

Out[35]:
           dept  col2  col3
date
2020-05-06    A    64    21
2020-05-07    B    41    12
2020-05-08    C    95    15
2020-05-09    D    58     9
2020-05-10    E    89    13
2020-05-11    F    37    87
2020-05-12    G    24     9
2020-05-13    H    67    63
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`df.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
In [2162]: df1['col2'].update(df2['col2'])                                                                                                                                                                  

In [2163]: df1                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[2163]: 
            col2  col3 dept
date                       
2020-05-06    64    21    A
2020-05-07    41    12    B
2020-05-08    95    15    C
2020-05-09    58     9    D
2020-05-10    89    13    E
2020-05-11    37    87    F
2020-05-12    24     9    G
2020-05-13    67    63    H
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `concat` then `groupby`

```
df_out=pd.concat([df1,df2],sort=False).groupby(level=0).last()
Out[261]: 
            col2  col3 dept
date                       
2020-05-06    64  21.0    A
2020-05-07    41  12.0    B
2020-05-08    95  15.0    C
2020-05-09    58   9.0    D
2020-05-10    89  13.0    E
2020-05-11    37  87.0    F
2020-05-12    24   9.0    G
2020-05-13    67  63.0    H
```

Comment: Hi Yoben. I believe IIUC is an abbreviation for "if I understand correctly". I am not sure how well it is known, especially amongst ESL readers. Moreover, we want questions to have some certainty here - if you are not sure you understand correctly, could you seek some clarifications in the comments?